# Error with Bad Math Delimiter

Tags: math-mode, delimiters, inline

I am struggling with a Bad Math Delimiter error, could I please ask for some help with this issue?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{grffile} %Stops the file name of figures appearing
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\officialeuro}{%
  \ifmmode\expandafter\text\fi
  {\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{eurosym}\selectfont e}}

\title{UCFB Diss}
\author{danrawly}
\date{}


\title{Dissertation}
\author{}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{algorithmic}
 \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\textheight=23cm
\textwidth=16cm
\topmargin=-2cm
\oddsidemargin=0cm
\parindent=0mm
\pretolerance=2000
\tolerance=3000

\begin{document}  

$$t= \dfrac{(\bar{x_1}-\bar{x_2})}{\sqrt{\dfrac{S_1^2}{N_1} +\dfrac{S_2^2}{N_2}}}\)$$

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please update your question with a full minimal example instead of posting a sniplet. It compiles fine in a standard doc with `amsmath`. Also please don't use `$$...$$` that is not LaTeX but plain TeX and you have not mentioned whether you are using plain TeX or not.

Comment: Hi I have amended the code to show the packages that I am using :) This is a LaTeX document and not TeX